# Solid modules and algebraic loop spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, condensed-mathematics

**Background**. Let $X$ be an affine variety over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$. We can define then the *loop space* of $X$, denoted $\mathcal{L}X$, to be the functor taking a $k$-algebra $A$ to the set $X(A((t)))$. This is representable by an ind-scheme (of ind- infinite type). Intuitively this is the mapping space $\operatorname{Map}(D^{*},X)$, where $D^{*}$ is the formal punctured $k$-disk, $\operatorname{spec}k((t))$. This is not quite correct however, indeed for it to be correct we would need $\operatorname{spec}(A)\times D^{*}$ to be $\operatorname{spec}(A((t)))$, which it is not as soon as $A$ is infinite dimensional as a $k$ vector space.
Nonetheless viewing it as a mapping space seems reasonable, in particular there is a well defined *evaluation map* from the universal correspondence. Note that for this to work we cannot naively take $\mathcal{L}X\times D^{*}$, again we have to *complete* the product. For example if $X=\mathbb{A}^{1}$ with coordinate $x$, then $\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{L}X\times D^{*})$ must contain the two way infinite Laurent series $x(t):=\sum_{i}x_{i}t^{i}$, where the $x_{i}$ are the natural coordinates on loop space. Notice that the Laurent tails tend to $0$ in $\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{L}X)$.

**Question**. Is there a natural algebro-geometric context in which $X$, $D^{*}$ and $\mathcal{L}X$ all live, so that we genuinely have $\operatorname{Map}(D^{*},X)\cong\mathcal{L}X$? Such a context must handle pro-discrete objects and adic ones in which a uniformiser is inverted. In particular can I use solid $k$-modules to build an appropriate context?

**Naive guess**. Thanks to Clausen-Scholze, we have a very well behaved symmetric monoidal category of *solid* $k$-modules. I believe that all the objects above sit naturally in this category, and that the products are as required. For example, if $A$ is a pro-discrete $k$-algebra, then $A\otimes_{\operatorname{solid}}k((t))$ is (as a module at least) the algebra of two way infinite Laurent series whose Laurent tails tend to $0$, according to [Solid tensor product of pro-discrete space with Laurent series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418942/solid-tensor-product-of-pro-discrete-space-with-laurent-series?noredirect=1#comment1075606_418942).

I cannot locate in the Clausen-Scholze work a definition of space modeled on the symmetric monoidal category $\operatorname{Solid}_{k}$, which leads me to believe that either it is a very special case of the analytic rings constructions, or that it is not useful.

Comment: They are adic spaces. The punctured open disk is discussed in §4.1 of [Berkeley lecture notes](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Berkeley.pdf). As for relation to condensed mathematics, see the chapter on discrete Huber pairs of [Condensed.pdf](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf) and [Analytic.pdf](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf).

Comment: @ZM ok so my understanding is that in the adic-spaces we do not have all pro-discrete algebras as "affine objects" but that if i consider Loops as an ind- adic thing then this is an honest mapping space etc? I was hoping a version of alg geom built from solid things would allow all three to be seen as affine

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, the solid tensor products do not quite work out this way. I haven't tried to look at loop groups from this perspective.